# CSS :focus doesn't do anything

Tags: html, css, focus

new here so sorry if I do something wrong.

I'm trying to use the CSS :focus, but it doesn't want to work.

I am trying to use it to show a drop down list when clicked

here is my code:

```css
button:focus + .ulprojects {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
        <div class="dropdown"> 

            <button><a href="#" class="home">home</a></button>
            <div class="projects">
                <button>projects</button>

                <ul class="ulprojects">
                    <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="products">
                <button>products</button>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

thanks in advance, please tell me what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Focus or on click? Which one? Could you confirm the need here?

Comment: i am trying to do something when the button is clicked. is there something onclick which i can use here?

Comment: you can hack with a checkbox or use JS and add a class to simulate a "focus". PS: dont use an nchor within a button or vice-versa. Its an invalid HTML markup. Either us an anchor as link to another resource or a button to fire a script. if you need both, add an onlcick trigger to the anchor directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your css you need to do this when you click on ulprojects button so you have to hide ulprojects by default and set it do display:block when you focus on a button.

```
    button:focus + .ulprojects {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: all;
    display:block!important;
}
.ulprojects{display:none}
```

See working demo:

```css
button:focus+.ulprojects {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
  display: block !important;
}

.ulprojects {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">

      <button><a href="#" class="home">home</a></button>
      <div class="projects">
        <button>projects</button>

        <ul class="ulprojects">
          <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="products">
        <button>products</button>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">product</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>


    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: I removed your fiddle and inserted a stacksnippet instead. Please do not use fiddles as a demonstration tool. If the link changes or getting deleted or the content of the fiddle changes, the anwser would hold no further value to the community. Code must always be demonstrated with a stack snippet (**Ctrl + M**). A fiddle may be used as extension to a stacksnippet but never as standalone.

Comment: sorry everyone, it was a problem with firefox, it blocks some pop ups i guess.. thanks for the help tho

Comment: @potato you are welcome :) glad to hear you figured it out